# Application using FFMPEG Library does not compile with CMAKE error avformat_alloc_context but I have imported the header files and libray

Tags: c++, cmake, ffmpeg

I compiled the FFMPEG source file myself and got the header and library files in an include and bin folder respectively, the target platform is Windows 10. I also setup my cmakelist.txt to find and include both the library and header files. The application finds the path or so it seems because during compilation I get a "LNK2019 error unresolved external symbol avformat_alloc_context referenced in function main". Below is an extract from my cmake list; I will like to note that I got the .lib and .dll versions of the library hence the approach below based on the book "professional cmake" and other stackflow examples.

ProjectDir/AudMan/cmakelist.txt

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH};PATH-TO-INCLUDES;PATH-TO-LIBRARY)
find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)
add_library(ffmpegHeaders INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(ffmpegHeaders INTERFACE ${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

ProjectDir/cmakelist.txt

```
set(Rapid_Prefix PATH-TO-LIBRARY)
    add_library(AVformat SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(AVformat PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${Rapid_Prefix}/avformat-59.dll IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(App_target PRIVATE AVformat)
```

A sample of the codes is this

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

int main()
{
    AVFormatContext* format = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (avformat_open_input(&format, R"(\test.m4a)", NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file '%s'\n", R"(\test.m4a)");
        return -1;
    }
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(format, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not retrieve stream info from file '%s'\n", R"(test.m4a)");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have been at it for about five days and will appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Is this the only error? Please post the error dump from the beginning.

Comment: Should `${AVCODEC_LIBRARY}` be `${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY}`? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you for the observation. Moving so many things around and so mixed things Up, Painful this got me stuck for 5hours+. Applied the Fix though and the error has changed.  The application Runs and a dialog box pops up with the following message "The code execution cannot proceed because avformat-59.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem".  This was the original error before I started moving things around in cmake. If you note I have the both library file set in the cmakelixt.txt file

Comment: I'd guess you need to put `avformat-59.dll` on your path somewhere or copy it into your application directory

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for your support. Yes I did what you said and they both worked. I first copied the files to the output folder of the exe file and it worked. For convenience though, I removed it and set the path in the PATHS environmental variable and it worked fine. Thank you and I mark this question as answered